# How can i get pop-ups in django admin interface?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-admin

I have the following code in admin.py file respectively. When i click on delete link i don't want to go delete page directly. simply i  want a pop up to be displayed like (are you sure?). Any way to do this? if so please mention here.

```
def delete_link(self, obj):
        info = obj._meta.app_label, obj._meta.model_name
        url = reverse('admin:%s_%s_delete' % info, args=(obj.id,))

        return '<a href="%s">Delete</a>' % url

  delete_link.allow_tags = True
  delete_link.short_description = 'Delete'

def action_link(self, obj):            

        app_name = obj._meta.app_label
        url_name = obj._meta.model_name
        data_id = obj.id

                 return """
            <ul>

               <li><a href="/admin/{0}/{1}/{2}/delete">Delete</a></li>

            </ul>
            """.format(
            obj._meta.app_label, 
            obj._meta.model_name, 
            obj.id)
  action_link.allow_tags = True
  action_link.short_description = 'Actions'
```

Comment: Well it *is* possible, you would have to override the relevant templates and apply some javascript logic in them.

Comment: I don't know how to do.
Can you please tell me?